# Onclick toggle as well as on hover change class without using css hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 boxes. Inside each big box(red) there is a small box(black by default but grey on hover).

1. On hover red box the small box color should change (It's changing now so ok).
2. When you click red box the black box should change to grey(which is working) and at the same time when you mouse over other boxes then it should do same as point 1(which is working too). But the problem begins here. When you click the red box the black box changes to grey and when you click again that red box the grey box is not changing to black. So the black box should toggle(black to grey and then grey to black) in every click to red box.
3. I can't use any css :hover effect.

Jquery

```
$('.libg').click(function () {
    $('this').find('.imagebg').removeClass("clicked").toggleClass('active');
    $(this).find('.imagebg').toggleClass("clicked");
}).hover(

function () {
    if (!$(this).find('.imagebg').hasClass("clicked")) $(this).find('.imagebg').addClass('active');
},

function () {
    if (!$(this).find('.imagebg').hasClass("clicked")) $(this).find('.imagebg').removeClass('active');
});
```

Is there anything to do with (data clicked true).

Here is the jfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/PTZE9/5/

Comment: i found grey boxes toggling back to black in your fiddle!

Comment: It seems to be working the in the fiddle the way you described. However it should $(this) and not $('this').

Comment: What i see wrong is :hover doesn't work after the clicks

Comment: @optionaloptional yes it is but only if you mouseout from the box. Once you click the red box the black box goes green not try to toggle it by clicking again but without moving your mouse out from the red box.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  extra ' ' from `$('this')`

Use

```
$(this).find('.imagebg').removeClass("clicked").toggleClass('active');
```

instead

```
$('this').find('.imagebg').removeClass("clicked").toggleClass('active');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PTZE9/6/)

Comment: Good spot on. I have removed the ''. But now when you click first time the black box is not changing to grey but if you click 2nd time then it is changing.http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/PTZE9/10/

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra It works clearly! it toggles between grey and red on every click.

Comment: Dhaval yes it works clearly. But what I want is when you click first time in the red box the black box should change to grey box. It's happening but in next click.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do. Solved now. http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/PTZE9/17/ Thanks

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra ohh i see! But i don't see any toggle effect

Comment: Sorry mate...here goes the updated version ... http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/PTZE9/18/

Comment: You can edit my answer and fiddle also so that it can help others :)

Comment: Dhaval that's alright. I won't mind if you please do it for me as you are the one who spotted 'this'. Thanks